# Fallout 4 how to stop dog from opening doors?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4 my dog keeps opening closed doors which is really annoying.

Short of leaving him or shooting him, is there a way to make him behave, you know, more like a real dog that cannot manipulate doorknobs and such?

I would even settle for a console command or UGC. (PC version)

Comment: to be fair: Bethesda really improved the dog from last version, ie: that super obnoxious 'panting' sound loop in Skyrim and FO3, and added cute behavior like rolling in the dirt

Comment: Shooting him won't make him behave, sadly. I pumped him full of lead after he killed me by triggering a bunch of tripwire booby traps, and he still triggered them again. What I did was tell him to "Stay", then "Follow" once I was done disarming all of them. This is probably not very practical for doors, though.

Comment: Thanks Nolonar - stay/follow commands seem to be best option here - if you post as answer I will accept.

Comment: I just ditched the bloody dog right after I met Piper whom I continue to impress with my mad lock picking skills. Unfortunately, all AI by Bethesda is very badly made. All NPC in Fallout 4 appear to be heavily brain-damaged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only thing you can do to get Dog(meat) from opening doors and get in your way, is to tell him to "*stay*". Don't forget to have him "*follow*" you later on.

Injuring him is not a very efficient solution, as it takes a long time to critically wound him, and he'll quickly recover to leave even more mayhem in his wake. It's much faster and more reliable to have him stay instead.

One thing I've noticed, is that you can close the door right in your dog's face. He won't attempt to open the door again unless you move away from it. I don't know if that's a reliable method, though, as I've only done it once so far.

Comment: what bugged me more than anything is that every time I left my base and shut the doors behind me he would run back and open them again... so rude.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for necro-ing this thread/question.

Since that seriously annoyed me, too, I searched for a solution and this Page showed up pretty much at the top at Google. Therefore, I wanted to share the solution for other users who come here with the same intention.

There's a mod for this (at least for PC) on nexus:

Dogmeat - Doors are NOT for Dogs (No Door Opening) 
by Ulithium_Dragon

http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/14702/

Comment: Necro-ing a post is always welcome if you have something useful to add, which it looks like you did! +1 and welcome to Arqade!